# What screws for attaching 1/2" ply to 3/4" ply?

Tags: screws, subfloor, plywood

I was using all-purpose screws (1 1/4") to attach my second layer of plywood to the under layer. The top layer does not get screwed into the floor joists. A lot of the screws just spin and don't sink into the floor like I want them to.

Am I using the wrong screws?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to pilot and counter-sink screws like that, or try switching to a self piloting, self counter-sinking screw like Gold Star or similar. The problem with all purpose screws is that the blunt tip just flexes the fibers out of the way, reducing the amount of material the threads can get a hold of. With a screw that short it doesn't get enough bite to pull the head flush so it strips out. With a Gold Star, the burr on the tip severs the fibers, allowing the threads to bite in all the way around,  then the nibs on the bugle help the head burrow in so you don't have to counter-sink.

Comment: That looks promising. Do you think I can find these at Home Depot or other big box stores?

Comment: Oh yeah,  maybe not Gold Stars specifically but there's many brands (almost always torx drive for some reason).

Comment: I picked up some self piloting/self countersinking screws and they work great. I also added a little bit of length so they will stick through the plywood floor slightly but provide a little more to latch on to.

Comment: Outstanding. Good luck with your project!